# iText PDF document should contain 3 columns

Tags: java, itext, documents

My question is that how to do the following thing.
I want to divide my pdf into three columns.

So if i add a paragraph it will just go to the first column and will continue to second column if the first column is already complete/full. I hope you understand my question. I'm not good in English.

I'm using iText PDF for this.

For example I have a table that looks like this:

```
9:00AM Meal 1  
Chicken
```

Now if that table will have 1000+ columns, I want it to continue in the next column of the first page. Heres my code for the table and please guide me how to do it cause I'm just a beginner.

```
try {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);


    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\PURCHASEORDER\\" + one + ".pdf"));
    document.open();


    Rectangle rect0 = writer.getPageSize();
    PdfPTable table0 = new PdfPTable(new float[]{6, 4});
    table0.setTotalWidth(527);
    table0.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    table0.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table0.addCell(new Paragraph("****************D", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 18, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    table0.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    table0.addCell(new Paragraph("**********************************", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    table0.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    table0.addCell(new Paragraph("**************************", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, BaseColor.BLACK)));
    table0.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));


    table0.setWidthPercentage(100);
    document.add(table0);


    try {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 25, 25, 25);


        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\PURCHASEORDER\\" + one + ".pdf"));
        document.open();


        Rectangle rect0 = writer.getPageSize();
        PdfPTable table0 = new PdfPTable(new float[]{6, 4});
        table0.setTotalWidth(527);
        table0.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table0.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table0.addCell(new Paragraph("FABLUES PAZFOOD", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 18, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        table0.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        table0.addCell(new Paragraph("#15 13th-15th Street, Nazareth, Cagayan de Oro", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        table0.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        table0.addCell(new Paragraph("Tel No: (088) 8571296/728-901", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, BaseColor.BLACK)));
        table0.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));


        table0.setWidthPercentage(100);
        document.add(table0);


        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String zero = dates.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String sql = "select count(*) as hehe from purchaseorder where servedate = '" + zero + "' and time = 'AM'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            Rectangle react = writer.getPageSize();
            PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(new float[]{7, 3});
            table2.setTotalWidth(527);
            table2.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(""));
            cell.setColspan(8);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            table2.addCell(cell);
            table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);


            if (rs.next()) {

                String v1 = rs.getString("hehe");


                table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                table2.addCell(new Paragraph("KITCHEN AM- " + one + "", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                table2.addCell(new Paragraph("TOTAL Number: " + v1 + "", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, BaseColor.BLACK)));


            }
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));


            table2.setWidthPercentage(100);
            document.add(table2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }


        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String zero = dates.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String sql = " Select purchaseorder.po_id,concat(purchaseorder.servetime,' ',purchaseorder.time) as times, customer.customer from purchaseorder join customer on customer.customer_id = purchaseorder.customer_id where servedate = '" + zero + "' and purchaseorder.time = 'AM' order by servetime DESC";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            Rectangle react = writer.getPageSize();
            PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(new float[]{2, 4, 2, 4, 4});
            table2.setTotalWidth(527);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(""));
            cell.setColspan(8);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            table2.addCell(cell);


            table2.getDefaultCell().setBorder(NO_BORDER);

            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));


            while (rs.next()) {


                String v0 = rs.getString("po_id");

                String v1 = rs.getString("times");
                String v2 = rs.getString("customer");


                table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table2.addCell(new Paragraph("" + v1 + "", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table2.addCell(new Paragraph("" + v2 + "", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));


                String ttt = "select type,code, quantity, stockname from orderlistview where po_id = '" + v0 + "'";
                pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(ttt);
                rs2 = pst1.executeQuery();

                while (rs2.next()) {

                    String a1 = rs2.getString("code");
                    String a2 = rs2.getString("type");

                    String b00 = rs2.getString("quantity");
                    String b11 = rs2.getString("stockname");


                    table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    table2.addCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    table2.addCell(new Paragraph("" + b00 + " " + b11 + "", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                }
            }
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, BaseColor.BLACK)));

            table2.setWidthPercentage(100);
            document.add(table2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

        document.close();

        String pdfFile = "D:\\PURCHASEORDER\\" + one + ".pdf";
        File f = new File(pdfFile);
        if (pdfFile.toString().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + pdfFile);
        } else {
            //For cross platform use
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

            desktop.open(f);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-divide-page-n-parts-so-we-can-fill-each-different-source) shows how to divide a page into sections, horizontally. In your case, make it vertically by defining 3 long-shaped rectangles instead of wide-shaped in the example.

Official [example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples-itext5/columntext-and-font-ascender) edited to make 3 long shaped columns.

```
private void createPdf(String dest){

        try{
            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            // show the area for the column as a rectangle with red borders
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 160, 800);
            addColumn(writer, rect, false);
            rect = new Rectangle(170, 10, 330, 800);
            addColumn(writer, rect, true);
            rect = new Rectangle(340, 10, 490, 800);
            addColumn(writer, rect, true);
            // step 5
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void addColumn(PdfWriter writer, Rectangle rect, boolean useAscender) throws DocumentException {
        rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        rect.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
        rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.rectangle(rect);
        Phrase p = new Phrase("This text is added at the top of the column.");
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
        ct.setSimpleColumn(rect);
        ct.setUseAscender(useAscender);
        ct.addText(p);
        ct.go();
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting it. t_T

Comment: What are you not getting?

Comment: Add your code to your question and tell us exactly what you are not getting. I understand that you are not good at English. If you show your code then it will be easier to understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, Stack Overflow recommends that you not just dump a link, but that you also include the relevant information in your answer.

Comment: Im not sure if this is what you want, hope it'll lead you to some direction, good luck :)

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. The OP has a table of which he wants to show 3 columns a page. That can only be done using the `writeSelectedRows()` method.

Comment: Sir Bruno do you have same sample for that writeSelectedRows() method?